# WSO2 Enterprise Store

Tags: tcp, wso2, wso2-es

I am trying to create a mobileapp store using WSO2 ES 1.0.I have installed all the prerequisites.I will have to create a new Asset for mobileapps as per documentation.
I am trying to access the admin URL: 9443/admin/carbon/ but getting error:

"Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team. "

My wso2server.bat is running and I am able to access the store using URL:https://192.168.XX.XX:9763/store but due to the above error I cannot register as a user and hence cannot download anything from the store.
Could there be a problem with my TCP port? Is firewall related to this? Any help?

Comment: what is the error that you got in console?

Comment: I am using "wso2server.bat run" command.I see the store page in my browser using the "store" URL,but when I try to bookmark a website or download an ebook it asks for login,redirects to 9443 port and shows "webpage not available" error.Console on the other hand shows "Emitting event: tenantLoad" and no error as such.

Comment: I think there is no service running on 9443 port.How can I detect or solve this?Are we supposed to run another .bat?

Comment: once you startup server carbon console will up on 9443  by default. Have you done any port offset?

Answer (score 1):

Try on this.

```
 https://localhost:9443/admin/carbon/
```

seems you have missed https on it..

Comment: Thanks Dakshika, There were issues with my browser security.The problem has gone away now.